# Is it possible to instantiate a javascript class from a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm wondering if I can do something like the following in Javascript:

1. Have a set of ES6 classes that I have defined (we'll call these components)
2. Have a function where I pass the name of the class and then within the function I instantiate a new class based on the argument that was passed
3. Do stuff with the new instantiated class

So if I have some code like the following in a components.js file:

```js
export class ComponentOne {}

export class ComponentTwo {}

export class ComponentThree {}
```

Then in another file I have the following code:

```js
import {ComponentOne, ComponentTwo, ComponentThree} from './components';

function addComponentToEntity(componentId, entityId) {
  //componentId is the name of the Class that needs to be instantiated
  let comp = new componentId;

  //Do stuff with the newly instantiated class and add it to the entity
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate a class from a variable like I've outlined above? Or what is the correct way of doing this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do..

```
import components from './components';
```

`components` will now be an object containing a property for each `export` within the `components.js` file.

So you can either do..

```
var c1 = components.ComponentOne // or...
var c1 = components['ComponentOne']
```

So you can do this: (from your example)

```
import components from './components';

function addComponentToEntity(componentId, entityId) {
  //componentId is the name of the Class that needs to be instantiated
  let comp = new components[componentId];

  //Do stuff with the newly instantiated class and add it to the entity
}
```

Comment: So what would the components object look like? The rest makes sense, but I'm not sure how to put that components object together. I apologize if this is something pretty basic.

Comment: The components object is created from the import statement.

Comment: Yes, `comp` will be a new instance of `components.Component1`. If you have any specific question about class initiation, let me know

Comment: Basically.. any methods declared in the `Component1` class will be available to the instance (comp)

Comment: Oh I see, so the ES6 import functionality is wrapping every export I've defined in my components.js file into the "components" object that I then use to instantiate the specific class that I need in that file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. We can start a chat session if you want more clarifications

Comment: Okay that's pretty awesome. I think that answers my question - thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: if you do multiple `export` as you are doing, each export has 2 bindings, a local and an external. Example: `export class ComponentOne`. the name `ComponentOne` exists locally (local binding), but externally it's also accessible through `import { ComponentOne } from './components'` or, if you want ALL bindings, you can do `import components` as in my example...

Comment: I just edited the answer because I was using Component1 instead of ComponentOne and that wouldn't work.. of course

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object with all of the names, so you can use an indexer:

```
import classes from './components'

new classes[componentId];
```